# Report opens Blank in ADF

Tags: jasper-reports

I have report1.jrxml which have simple SQL query with no parameters and runs fine in iReport. I want to open this report through ADF. 
my reportAction method is as follows:

```
public void reportAction(FacesContext ctx,OutputStream output) throws FileNotFoundException,NamingException,
                                     SQLException, IOException, JRException,
                                     ClassNotFoundException,
                                     InstantiationException,
                                     IllegalAccessException {
    File input = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Map reportParameters = new HashMap();
    bindings = this.getBindings();
    ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    String reportPath = ctx.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("reportpath");
    input = new File(reportPath+"report1.jasper");
    if(bindings!=null){


            OperationBinding ob = bindings.getOperationBinding("getCurrentConnection");
            ob.execute();
            conn = (Connection)ob.getResult();

    if(input.getPath()!=null&&reportParameters!=null&&conn!=null){
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(input.getPath(),reportParameters,conn);
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report1.pdf");
        output = response.getOutputStream();
        String userName = "ilpa";
        File outPutPDF = new File("D:/jdev libs/reports/report1.pdf");
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, output);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,outPutPDF.getPath());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }        
}
else{
    ctx.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage("No bindings configured for this page"));
}
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check the report in `iReport`?

Comment: Yea. It's working in iReport.

Comment: Actually, I have corrected the above Exception. It was because of the usage of .jrxml file. I have replaced it with .jasper. Now a new exception has occured and it is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid UTF8 encoding

Comment: You should correct the question. Can you post the jrxml file?

Comment: Why you are using `JRXmlLoader.load` for loading `jrxml` file? You can use the code like this: `JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "\\report.jrxml"); JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params); JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now I face a different error: It says :Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:63)". I don't have any parameters to my report, so I haven't added it in the Java.

Comment: You can add the empty map - it is not a problem. You should post the code.

Comment: Hi. I have added the empty map and now the report gets opened, but it shows blank. There are no contents shown when it runs properly with contents in iReport.

Comment: My button code is"      <af:commandButton text="Report"
                          binding="#{backingBeanScope.reportDemo.cb1}"
                          id="cb1" partialSubmit="true">
          <af:fileDownloadActionListener
                                         method="#{backingBeanScope.reportDemo.reportAction}"
                                         filename="report1.jrxml"
                                         contentType="application/pdf"/>
        </af:commandButton>

Comment: It is better to add the source code to the question

Comment: I have added the source code to the question. Please check and help.

Comment: What do you mean `blank`? Do you have Title band? Did you try to pass parameters?

Comment: I have a title band. I have a static field out there. in Detail band I have a table which is the result of the SQL Query. This query is a simple select statement with no bind variables. So I haven't added any report parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself.

The root cause was I was giving a wrong path in web.xml.

That is, I had report1.jrxml in two locations. The actual report I was using was in a different location.